# Play Framework 2 + java does not return URL dynamic part in getQueryString call

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

This may be a duplicate question but I was not able to find a solution. As a result, I'm posting my own one.

My URL looks like this "/customer/www.bakeryx.com" where **www.bakeryx.com** is the URL dynamic part and maps to "/customer/:domain".

I was hoping that when I call **ctx.request().getQueryString("domain")** I would get the www.bakeryxcom. Otherwise, I get a null response and there is no way to get this value from the action.

Please find bellow my work around for this task. I had to get the ROUTE_PATTERN from the context args.

```java
 public class DomainVerifierAction extends Action<DomainVerifierFilter> {
      @Override
      public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
         //how to get the domain here??

         //work around is to get the route_pattern 
         String routePatternPlay = (String) ctx.args.get("ROUTE_PATTERN");
         String path = ctx.request().path();

         //added logic to extract domain from the PATH using ROUTE_PATTERN.
      }
 }
```

**Question:** Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: So passing the domain name input as a parameter (i.e. `controllers.Application.function(domain: String)` in routes, then in your Play controller using `public static Result function(String domain){...}` method) doesn't work for you?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that because this is an action composition! It is not a controller.

Comment: Ok, you should probably elaborate that in your question to make it more clear.  I just assumed your workaround used an Action for reasons unknown.

Comment: if you look at the code I wrote in the question, you will see that it is not a controller, but an action composition.

Comment: Right, but you could still write the question content a lot better. Instead of voting people down who actually tried something, you should work on explaining yourself and framing your questions better.

Comment: are you able to fix it properly? I am also stuck in same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem you are having is that the `getQueryString` method you are using is looking for the "?" operator in the URL, as in a traditional GET request (e.g. `?id=1`).  Instead, try passing the domain as a parameter in the controller method.  For example:

In your `routes` file:

```
GET   /customer/:domain   controllers.Application.function(domain: String)
```

Then in your Play controller (assuming Play Framework 2.x):

```
public static Result function(String domain){
         //Do something with the passed domain string here
       return ok(...);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that because this is an action composition! It is not a controller.

Comment: Ok, you should probably elaborate that in your question to make it more clear. I just assumed your workaround used an Action for reasons unknown.